# Grunt copy task won't copy over all folders and files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm a bit new to grunt and am trying to get it to copy over the entire contents of the src directory (App) to the dest directory (build).

It's only copying over the App folder but none of it's child folders and files. How can I get it to copy over everything? Any help would be really appreciated. Please see my gruntfile below.

thanks - chris

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {


    // INITIALIZE TASKS
    grunt.initConfig({    


        // PACKAGE INFO
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


        // ENVIRONMENT SETTINGS
        env: 'dev',


        // CLEAN BUILD FOLDER
        clean: {
            options: {
                force: true
            },

            build: [
                'build/App/buildlates',
                'build/App/styles/app',
                'build/App/styles/vendor',
                'build/App/scripts/app',
                'build/App/scripts/vendor',
                'build/App/scripts',
                'build/App/styles',
                'build/App/img',
                'build/App',
                'build'
            ]
        },


        // COPY DEV CODE INTO BUILD
        copy: {

            main: {
                files: {
                    'build/': ['App/**']
                }

            }
        },


        // JSHINT
        jshint: {

            files: [
                    'App/scripts/app/angular/**/*.js'
            ],
            options: {
                ignores: [
                    'App/scripts/app/*.js',
                    'App/scripts/app/angular/directives/vendor/**'
                ]
            }

        },


        // LESS PROCESSING
        less: {

            development: {
                options: {
                    paths: ['build/App/styles/app']
                },
                files: {
                    'build/App/styles/app/css/main.css': 'build/App/styles/app/main.less',
                    'build/App/styles/app/css/another.css': 'build/App/styles/app/another.less'
                }
            }

        },


        // CONCAT
        concat: {

            css : {
                src: ['build/App/styles/app/css/*.css'],
                dest: 'build/App/styles/app/css/styles.css'
            },

            js : {
                src: [
                        'build/App/scripts/app/angular/*.js',
                        'build/App/scripts/app/angular/objects/*.js',
                        'build/App/scripts/app/angular/modules/*.js',
                        'build/App/scripts/app/angular/services/*.js',
                        'build/App/scripts/app/angular/directives/*.js',
                        'build/App/scripts/app/angular/filters/*.js',
                        'build/App/scripts/app/angular/controllers/*.js'
                ],
                dest: 'build/App/scripts/app/angular/release/app.js'
            }

        },


        // MINIMIZE CSS    
        cssmin: {

            minify: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'build/App/styles/app/css/',
                src: ['styles.css', '!*.min.css'],
                dest: 'build/App/styles/app/css/',
                ext: '.min.css'
            }

        },


        // MINIMIZE JAVASCRIPT
        'jsmin-sourcemap': {
            all: {
                src: ['build/App/scripts/app/angular/release/app.js'],
                dest: 'build/App/scripts/app/angular/release/app.min.js',
                destMap: 'build/App/scripts/app/angular/release/app.js.map'
            }
        },


        // WATCH FOR CHANGES
        watch: {

            src: {
                options: { livereload: true },
                files: ['App/scripts/app/**', 'App/styles/app/*.less', 'App/templates/**'],
                tasks: ['jshint', 'less', 'preprocess'],
            }

        },


        // PREPROCESS HTML BUILD DIRECTIVES
        preprocess: {

            options: {
                context: {
                    ENVIRONMENT: '<%= env %>'
                }
            },

            html: {
                src: 'App/templates/environmentChecker.html',
                dest: 'build/App/templates/environmentChecker.html'
            }


        }


    });



    // LOAD TASKS
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jsmin-sourcemap');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-preprocess');


    // REGISTER TASKS
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean:build', 'copy', 'jshint']);
    grunt.registerTask('dev', ['jshint', 'clean:build', 'clean:build', 'copy', 'less:development', 'preprocess', 'watch']);
    grunt.registerTask('prod', ['jshint', 'clean:build', 'clean:build', 'copy', 'less:development', 'concat:css', 'cssmin', 'concat:js', 'jsmin-sourcemap', 'preprocess']);


};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration you specified only looks at the root directory; if you want the whole folder why not just specify that?

```
copy: {
    main: {
        files: {
            'build': 'App'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for replying! Unfortunately, this copied over nothing :-(

Comment: If you found my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted. Thank you.